# Javascript return false; is not cancelling a form submit for another .submit jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this jQuery function injected on every page in order to disable submit buttons after they are clicked.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
        var btn = $('input[type=submit]', this);
        disableButtonOrLink.disableSubmit(btn);

        btn = $('button[type=submit]', this);
        disableButtonOrLink.disableSubmit(btn);
    });
```

The problem is that I also have some backend validation that is sometimes attached to the form in the the shape of something like this

```
 <form action="someAction" method="post" name="someForm" class="form" 
    onsubmit="var invalid=false; 
    invalid=someAction(); 
    if(invalid){return false;}"
    id="someForm">
```

The issue I am having that is occurs is that the ('form').submit action is always being called after the return false. The form isn't actually being submitted due to the return false; however this jQuery function is still being called after. Is there anyway to prevent this .submit from being called?

Just to clarify exactly what is happening:
The onSubmit on the form is being called;

The return false section is being hit and properly canceling the submit;

The ('form').submit is still being called after the onSubmit completes as if the form's submit wasn't canceled and is disabling buttons.

I would like to prevent the last step from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to find those buttons inside `form` and use a method from preventing stuff that they normally do.
Example:
`$("form button").on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: In my example, it gets every `button` element that is inside  a `form`. The `e.preventDefault()` stop from default action that element does - in example of buttons in a form - from sending it.  
#Edit - actually, it will be more clear if I would catch `input` with type of `submit` - default action in this case is submitting the form

Comment: Is there a way to use the .preventDefault() in the onsubmit section if it is written in html? I.E. onSubmit=" something.preventDefault()" as this.preventDefault() does not seem to be working

Comment: Notice my example where I pass 'e' argument that later I use .preventDefault() on

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try something like this

```
$('#someForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('some-action')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    //... then disable buttons, etc
});
```

In this case you need to add the attribute `data-some-action` to the form, evaluated with whatever backend validation you are doing.

**UPDATE**

```
$('#someForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($(this).data('some-action') == 'error-message') {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('error!');
        return false;
    }
    if ($(this).data('some-action') == 'reload') {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
    //... then disable buttons, etc
});
```

Comment: So essentially set an attribute on the form before return false; that indicated whether it is valid or not which could then be evaluated in my .submit jQuery to determine if it should disable the buttons or not.

Comment: With the code above i believe you can skip the whole `onsubmit="var invalid=false; invalid=someAction(); if(invalid){return false;}"` just remove it. add instead `data-some-action=""` evaluated true or false depending on if you want to submit the form or not

Comment: I kinda of like this idea however the behaviour changes page to page as how to handle an invalid submission (anywhere from just rendering an error message to re-rendering the whole page). This solution unfortunately wouldn't allow for me to keep each validation action unique.

Comment: @mcgray i made a jsfiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/h0jc8tf7/1/ . Change the value of data-some-action (0 or 1). Hope this helps. Anyway data-some-action can be evaluated with whatever value you want. Then you just need to add the logic to handle error messages, page reloads, etc